# Error Running command in Windows PowerShell Modules

Tags: python, windows, cmd

When i execute .\install.bat on C:\Install\IBM_Docs\DocsConversion\DocsConversion\installer where the "install" file is.

```
Traceback(most recent call last):

File "conversion/install.py", line 219, in <module>
 if not pi.do();
File "C:\Install\IBM_Docs\DocsConversion\DocsConversion\installer\conversion\prepare_install.py", line 100 in do
 if not self.verify_was();
File "C:\Install\IBM_Docs\DocsConversion\DocsConversion\installer\conversion\prepare_install.py", line 78, in verify_was
  succ, ws_out = call_wsadmin(args)
File "C:\Install\IBM_Docs\DocsConversion\DocsConversion\installer\util\common.py", line 24, in call_wsadmin
 stdout=ws_log, stderr=ws_log
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in ___init___
 errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948. in _execute_child
 startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The System cannot find the file specified
```

I've already double check if the "install.bat" is on the directory and it is their.
What seems to be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: File not specified, is the file actually there? What are you trying to do exactly? Are you running python in command prompt?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yep the file is actually there. I;m trying to run the "install.bat" because on my reference which is http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/docswiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Installing+and+deploying+IBM+Docs+1.0.3+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Installing_the_Conversion_server_id103&content=pdcontent the next step is to install "install.bat" in a silent installation. So i execute .\install.bat on windows powershell module.

Comment: If you're running a bat file (and the bat file is running python), you're not in PowerShell.

Comment: @MikeSheoard so how will i run it? Sorry im just new on installing IBM Docs and for python commands

Comment: If it is a batch file (.bat), you can either double-click on it or run from command prompt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392874/bat-file-open-new-cmd-window-and-enter-code-in-there.

Comment: @JaredBurrows but the step say's that i should run it on powershell module. and have the silent installation done there.

Comment: Can you give us more information? Where you got your instructions? What software you trying to install? A link? More info?

Comment: @JaredBurrows http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/docswiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Installing+and+deploying+IBM+Docs+1.0.3+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Installing_the_Conversion_server_id103&content=pdcontent Here's the link. Specifically step F. I'm installing ibm docs on ibm connections.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the arguments that are being passed. What is the value of `ws_log`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the path to python.exe to your windows system variables.