# How to start MingW Console (GitBash) from Command Line on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, git-bash

I'm trying to automate my work environment set up using a batch file. I'm stuck at a point where I am not able to start the MingW64 Console from command line.

`start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login` works fine but it seems to open a different shell window than that I am looking for. I'll explain this with pictures.

What it opens is a default cmd style window with bash integrated. This window isn't even resizeable
[image]

What I want is
[image]

I was trying to use the command `start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe" --login -i -c /bin/bash` but it seems to quickly close the shell after opening it. If I execute the same file from explorer, the shell doesn't close automatically.

Here is my full batch file for reference

```
@echo on

REM start PHP and MYSQL
start "" mysql_server\UniServerZ\UniController.exe start_both

REM Open PhpMyAdmin
start "" http://localhost/us_opt1/

REM Open Folders
start "" %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "E:\work\"

REM Open Git Bash Instance
:: in order to open the shell in that path
cd E:\work\
:: start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe" --login -i -c /bin/bash

REM start sublime text
start "" "E:\Sublime Text Build 3083 x64\sublime_text.exe"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git-bash.exe -i -c "/bin/bash"` seems to work better.
[This issue](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/176) illustrates various other ways to call `git-bash.exe`, but concludes:

> Preferred way to run git-for-windows is using `git-cmd.exe`:

```
c:\git\git-cmd.exe --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i
```

That however only opens a session in the current cmd, while `git-bash.exe` opens a new windows.

[Combined with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393481/6309) (to open a new console) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298636/6309) (to avoid two CMD windows), I would use:

```
start /b cmd /c git-bash.exe -i -l -c "/bin/bash"
```

The [OP Atif Mohammed Ameenuddin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205024/atif-mohammed-ameenuddin) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252265/how-to-start-mingw-console-gitbash-from-command-line-on-windows/34252558#comment56288684_34252558) this as working fine:

```
start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this. `start /b cmd /c "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe" -i -l -c "/bin/bash"` doesn't seem to work, but `start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe"` works

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: While this is working for me, I'm finding I have to press Ctrl+C once the Git bash window opens in order to actually get to the prompt. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: @TimMalone Strange. What git version are you using? On which Windows?

Comment: @VonC 2.8.1 on Windows 10. Maybe I should try updating Git, I'm a little behind.

Comment: @TimMalone Agreed. Try the latest 2.15.

Answer (score 1):

work on windows 10

start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login

;

start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe"

tx !

Comment: You answer includes very little detail and nothing to indicate what new information your answer provides compared to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Oneline to open it in a different path, and for example execute a command:

```
start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd="E:\work" -c "git status; /bin/bash"
```

If there is a command it's always at the end.