# Cant run shell script using Git Bash interface on Windows10

Tags: git, batch-file, git-bash

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564275/windows-shortcut-to-run-git-bash-script) post I wasn't able run shell trough Git bash.
This is the batch file :

```
%ComSpec% /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --login -i -- C:\Users\rmrd001\Documents\Git\scripts\first\test.sh"
pause
```

This is the shell script:

```
echo Hello, World!
```

And this is what I get when batch is run:

[image]

I can see the instantaneous appearance of the bash program, but can't catch the text into it. 
I double-triple-checked the paths, they are correct.
I ran the script trough the Git bash, everything worked well (the message appeared).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a [different syntax before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34252558/6309).

I only see the message with:

```
start "" git-bash.exe -i -l -c "/C/path/to/script.sh"
```

With `script.sh` including [a pause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92813/6309):

```
echo Hello. World!
read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key
```

The [OP Hairi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5598574/hairi) report [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200723/cant-run-shell-script-using-git-bash-interface-on-windows10/39201200#comment65744485_39201200) making it work with:

```
start /b cmd /c "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe" /C/path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: This worked to me:

start /b cmd /c "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe" /C/Users/rmrd001/Documents/Git/scripts/first/test.sh

Comment: @Hairi Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.