# Get Git Shell to run command after starting

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, posh-git

You can do

```
start powershell -command ls
```

to open PowerShell and get it to list files. I'm trying to do a similar thing with Git Shell. Currently I have

```
%LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\Github.appref-ms --open-shell -command ls
```

which opens Git Shell, but doesn't do anything else. Is it possible to run a command after starting Git Shell in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Since this hasn't been answered I'm going to offer an alternative solution of using git-bash instead of the MS application reference file.

```
start /b cmd /c "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe" /C/path/to/script.sh
```

See this question: [Cant run shell script using Git Bash interface on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200723)