# Start application (needing user interaction) in a separate console window

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I know there are tons of questions on this topic but none seem to provide an answer that solves all my requirements.

**My requirements**:

- Start another application (should support all kinds of applications: long running processes taking **user input**, simple applications ending quickly or applications that take a long time)
- Should also be able to start applications that end immediately (ex: 'git status')
- It needs to start in a new console window
- The console window should remain active even after command completion to see the application output.
- It needs to be cross platform (Windows and Linux)

I want to use subprocess module. I already tried using the option CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

```
subprocess.Popen(("git", "status"), close_fds=True, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, shell=True)
```

but:

- It does not really work. I see no window starting, or may be it is starting but exiting too fast after command execution.
- this only works for Windows. Was wondering if there is a way to do this on all platforms consistently ?

Comment: some programs run system script (bash/bat) which runs expected program and `pause` program so window waits with results till you press some key.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to open a new console window with subprocess and run the command in that window. On Linux that can be achieved with the "-e" flag followed by the command.

For example (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531426)

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c \"git status; exec bash\""
```

will open a new window of the default terminal and run the command

```
bash -c "git status; exec bash"
```

in that window. In Python this would look like

```
subprocess.Popen('x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c \\"git status; exec bash\\""', shell=True)
```

---

Running "exec bash" at the end opens a new shell in the console window and prevents it from exiting immediately.

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393481/3092681), on Windows you can use "start cmd /k" and then run the command. I haven't tried it, but presumably something like

```
subprocess.Popen('start cmd /k git status', shell=True)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Although it is a working solution, one big disadvantage especially on Linux is one needs to know which terminal is installed before making a call. For example, I have 'konsole', but never know what others have !!!

Comment: The command "x-terminal-emulator" should on most systems open the default terminal emulator, and should still work with the "-e" option.