# How to write commands in second CMD using the first CMD

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, command-prompt

So I have a python file which I will run using VScode and then it should execute another python script in the background and should display output in new command prompt.

[This was quite helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392874/bat-file-open-new-cmd-window-and-execute-a-command-in-there#)

But when I execute`.\venv\scripts\activate.bat` to open the virtual  environment, I get stuck and cannot execute further commands... I know since its virtual environment we cannot communicate to it directly but is there a way/workaround to be able to execute commands even in the virtual environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean **How to run multiple commands one after another in cmd ?**

call command1
call command2
.
.
call commandx

```
 call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=spring.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=spring -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar 
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=com.ibm.ws.runtime -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=IMSConnection_Utilities.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=IMSConnection_Utilities -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```