# Windows batch file to open new window and issue command

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a batch file, `mybatch.cmd`, which successfully opens 3 command line windows:

```
start "CMD LINE 1" CD C:\dir1
start "CMD LINE 2" CD C:\dir2
start "CMD LINE 3" CD C:\dir3
```

But I want to expand this to issue a subsequent command (e.g., "echo test") within each new window. So I tried this:

```
start "CMD LINE 1" CD C:\dir1 echo test
start "CMD LINE 2" CD C:\dir2 echo test
start "CMD LINE 3" CD C:\dir3 echo test
```

But that gives me `The system cannot find the path specified`. Any suggestions?

I realize this question seems like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392874/bat-file-open-new-cmd-window-and-execute-a-command-in-there). But none of those answers are working for me.

Specifically, neither /c or /k seem to do the trick - though they do work when I remove the `CD` part of my command. It's almost like the `CD` is incompatible with the `/c` and `/k`.

**Solution:**

Fixed by modifying each line to 1) add cmd.exe; 2) put commands in quotes, separated by `&`:

```
start "CMD LINE 1" cmd.exe /D /K "CD C:\SOURCE & echo test"
```

Note it's probably best to specify the full path to cmd.exe, as shown in the answer below, but I left that off for simplicity (and it works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you're talking about, you need to specify the Command Prompt application executable `cmd.exe`:

You can perform the command used in your examples just like this:

```bash
@Start "CMD LINE 1" /D "C:\dir1" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K
@Start "CMD LINE 2" /D "C:\dir2" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K
@Start "CMD LINE 3" /D "C:\dir3" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K
```

If you didn't really want to just open the prompts with a specific directory as your current directory, then the following methodology may be better for you:

```bash
@Start "CMD LINE 1" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "CD /D "C:\dir1""
@Start "CMD LINE 2" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "CD /D "C:\dir2""
@Start "CMD LINE 3" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "CD /D "C:\dir3""
```

Obviously in the case of not really wanting to change directory, but to run another command or commands, *(linked together using ampersands)*, you would change `CD /D "C:\dirN"` with the actual command, but please ensure that you do not remove the enclosing doublequotes for the `/K` option.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `%ComSpec%` instead of `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` here or is that just a style choice?

Comment: It's not at all a style choice, @Qwerty, I have no idea what the end user has configured their `%ComSpec%` variable to be. The Command Specifier, is configurable, so whilst the default will be the standard location cmd.exe executable, it could have been changed to something else entirely. My command deliberately and robustly ensures that the standard location cmd.exe is used.