# Most compact elegant way to open a cmd window from batch file and start many lines of commands on it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There are several answers on this topic but they all refer to inline commands added to the cmd call such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392874/bat-file-open-new-cmd-window-and-execute-a-command-in-there). I want just to have a batch file that first opens a cmd.exe terminal that would not close (that is easy, `cmd /k` to keep it) and then in the same batch file below that `cmd /k` line I want  to have pages of commands that would be executed on the same cmd window. I could not find a way to do it, however this three-lines workaround makes it, is there any shorter way to make it with some fancy cmd flag I am not aware of?

```
@ECHO OFF
if "%1" == "" (
   start cmd /k %~nx0 SKIP 
   EXIT )
```

Comment: I wouldn't call your question on topic for this site. In my opinion something like this, would be only one line and also uses a fancy cmd flag: ```@Color 2>NUL&&(Start cmd /D/Q/S/Y/K ""%~f0""&Exit/B)||SetLocal EnableExtensions```

Comment: I should have added, the main benefit for me, over your own idea, _(which could also be one line: ```@Echo Off&If "%1"=="" (Start cmd /D/S/K ""%~nx0" _"&Exit/B```)_, is if you wanted to pass on the original scripts arguments. For example: ```@Color 2>NUL&&(Start %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D/Q/S/Y/K ""%~f0" %*"&Exit/B)||SetLocal EnableExtensions```. Obviously in your case `SKIP`, (or `_` in the first example above), would modify those and require additional work to remove again.